# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table c_library.template_details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

here is my application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=cLibrary
```

I searched my whole project but did not find c_library and still getting this error.

Earlier I was using a custom id generator later I removed it because while debugging it goes to         IdentifierValueBinding class and sets schema as c_library.

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace

Comment: `cLibrary` whill changed by hibernato to `c_library`by conventions

Comment: https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5/#CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy_in_Hibernate_554